# how WebRTC handles NAT rebinding?

Tags: networking, webrtc, nat, ice, quic

In a cellular environment, the ip address assigned for a phone changes dynamically.

So i wonder how WebRTC deals with this issue.

Does WebRTC has some feature called 'Path Migration' like QUIC ?

Is ICE Restart what i am finding?

Answer (score 0):

There is an RFC8016 TURN about mobility to reuse TURN session in case of IP change, but it is AFAIK not implemented in the actual WebRTC stack.

AFAIK WebRTC does not handle yet this case.

You could detect the error on client side and restart ICE agent.